# Regex to match words separated by '!' and enclosed between curly brackets '{' '}'

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to parse a string and get all the words enclosed between curly brackets {} that has '!' in it.
Input example:
`"This is {matchA} and {matchB} but I need {matchC!matchD}, however {matchE} doesn't count but {matchF!matchG} is what I'm looking for"`

I have used `(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})` and `{(?:\.|(\\{)|[^}'\n])*}` to get all the matches between the `{}` but it returns the following as matches:
`"matchA"`, `"matchB"`, `"matchC!matchD"`, `"matchE"` and `"matchF!matchG"` as matches

However, I'm trying to get only the matches that has '!' in them, so the result should be only: `"matchC!matchD"`, and `"matchF!matchG"` and ignores the rest.

I would really appreciate the help. Thank you all in advance for your answers

Comment: Is it required to do it with a single regex?  Couldn't you just pass the matches collection through `.Where(x => x.Value.Contains('!'))` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the exclamation mark in there and use character classes instead of non-greediness.

```
{([^}]+![^}]+)}
```

Comment: I like being greedy :(